# Puzzled over terminology "Indefinite Integral" in Royden

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In Royden (pg 125), a function of the form $$f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^x f'$$ is called an "indefinite integral" of $f'$ over $[a,b]$.

However, I don't see how it is "indefinite", I thought indefinite means it has no limits, something like $\int g$?

Thanks for any explanation.

[image]

Comment: $x$ varies within $[a,b]$; hence, the term indefinite.

Answer (score 2):

Indefinite doesn't really mean an integral without limits. It is an integral without "definite" limits, that is, without real numbers as the limits. Instead, one or both of the limits are variables.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't $f(a)$ an arbitrary constant because you can pick any $f(a)$? For each $f(a)$ you get a different antiderivative of $f'$.

You might write the indefinite integral as $\int f'(x)dx=f(x)+C$. But this is just the same as $f(x)+f(a)$ since we can take $f(a)$ to be any constant.

Comment: Thanks. But in the book, the interval $[a,b]$ is a given fixed interval.

Comment: I think the question is about the limits on the integral, not on the arbitrary constant attached to it.